# макрос на netbeans

Tags: netbeans

как сделать макрос, чтобы он корректно смещал строку вниз или вверх (наподбие как работает *sublime* <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ стрелка вверх или вниз)?

пробовал составлять макрос -  вот что получилось:

```
select-line cut-to-clipboard caret-end-line insert-break paste-from-clipboard
```

оно-то работает, но форматирование сбивается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно "правильно" описать функцию?